# CMS page id from system configurations Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, system-config, system-configuration

In my `custom module`, I have a field in the system `config`with `cms`pages. I need to get the `id` of the selected cms page, not the identifier, so I can get the content of a `cms` page in a phtml file.

I have the following lines in my `system.xml`

```
<cms_page translate="label">
         <sort_order>140</sort_order>
         <label>Cookie Information Page</label>
         <comment>Use this page for learn about cookie settings.</comment>
         <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
         <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cms_page</source_model>
         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</cms_page>
```

This is my `Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Page.php` of my module

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $pages = array();
    $cmspages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
    foreach($cmspages as $page){
        $pages[] = array('label' => $page->getTitle(), 'value' => $page->getPageId());
    }

    return $pages;
}
```

`config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Module>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </My_Module>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <My_Module>
                <files>
                    <default>My_Module.csv</default>
                </files>
            </My_Module>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <my_module>
                <file>my/module.xml</file>
            </my_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <my_module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>My_Module</module>
                <frontName>my_module</frontName>
            </args>
        </my_module>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_module_ctrl before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Module_Adminhtml</my_module_ctrl>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <My_Module>
                <files>
                    <default>My_Module.csv</default>
                </files>
            </My_Module>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Block</class>
        </my_module>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        </my_module>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Helper</class>
        </my_module>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <my_module_model_observer_buttons>
                    <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addButtons</method>
                </my_module_model_observer_buttons>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <my_module_model_observer_blocks>
                    <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>removeBlocks</method>
                </my_module_model_observer_blocks>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
    <resources>
        <my_module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>My_Module</module>
            </setup>
        </my_module_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Comment: Something like <block_id> your block_id </block_id>

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: can you add your config.xml code?

Answer (score 3):

Below is working code, replace your **system.xml** code with the below one:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    <sort_order>140</sort_order>
    <label>Cookie Information Page</label>
    <comment>Use this page for learn about cookie settings.</comment>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>[Vendor]_[Module]_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Cms_Page</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</cms_page>
```

Create **Page.php** file under the below location:

> [Vendor]/[Module]/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Cms/Page.php

and add the following code it **Page.php** :

```
<?php
class [Vendor]_[Module]_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Cms_Page
{
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
        $pages = array();
        $cmspages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
        foreach($cmspages as $page){
            $pages[] = array('label' => $page->getTitle(), 'value' => $page->getPageId());
        }

       return $pages;
   }
}
```

***Note: Replace the [Vendor], [Module] with your namespace and module name.***

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463` I get this error.

Comment: Did you create any module?

Comment: Can you post your module files in your question? I think you have not created the model I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create custom class for this, magento already has it

```
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cms_page</source_model>
```